# A joke about blind date

Tags: jokes

I cannot understand this joke on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/BadIuckBrian/status/205519901497110530):

> Has a blind date. The dates blind.

I know what blind date is, but what's the meaning of the second sentence?

Comment: That's not so much a "joke" as "an idea for a joke". It needs some work to get to the point where it's actually funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a missing apostrophe there: "date's"

"The date's blind" means his/ her date is literally blind or handicapped.